# Comparison of two sets of 4-tuples using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

My problem is to show that $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$. Specifically that $\forall a \in \mathbf{A} \implies a \in \mathbf{B}$ and $\forall b \in \mathbf{B} \implies b \in \mathbf{A}$, to be precise.

The sets are defined as sets of objects of 4 numbers each. A member of $\mathbf{A}$ is therefore of the form $(a,b,c,d)$. Two 4-tuples are equivalent if they contain the same numbers (and the same multiplicities of them, if applicable). Therefore $(-2,-6,9,8) = (-6,-2,8,9)$.

The set $\mathbf{A}$ contains **all** 4-tuples $(k,m,n,o)$ such that $k \geq 1$ and $m,n,o$ are can be any integers (positive or negative) **but not 0**.

The set $\mathbf{B}$ contains **all** 4-tuples $(-k,m,n,o)$ for the above defined ranges of $k,m,n,o$.

Now $\mathbf{A} \neq \mathbf{B}$. Proving that is easy via providing a counterexample.

The actual problem is this: Let $\mathbf{A}$ contain only such elements for which $k+m+n+o = 0$ and let $\mathbf{B}$ contain only such elements that $-k+m+n+o=0$. Now, **I want to show that $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$**. I tried looking for obvious symmetries but could not prove it. I also know it is true as I have written a program matching the terms (with some limit on the size of the numbers of course).

Could you please help me with this?

**Bonus question:**
Imagine that everything stated above holds, except the objects within A and B are of the form $(k,(m,n,o))$ and $(-k,(m,n,o))$ respectively. To have such two objects equal, the first terms must match, and the second terms (the 3-tuples) must contain the same elements, but ordering does not matter. The conditions $k+m+n+o = 0$ for A and $-k+m+n+o = 0$ for B still hold. Can you show whether $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$?

Thanks a lot!

SSF

Comment: How do you prove $\mathbf{A} \neq \mathbf{B}$? From the problem description, $\mathbf A=\mathbf B=\{(1,1,1,-1)\}$ sems to be allowed?

Comment: My bad, it includes all such tuples. Edited.

Comment: By the way, tuples that are treated like you're treating them (order doesn't matter, repetition matters) are called "unordered tuples" (as opposed to "ordered tuples", where order matters, and "sets", where repetition doesn't matter / isn't allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ is that tuples in $\mathbf A$ are guaranteed to have at least one positive element and tuples in $\mathbf B$ are guaranteed to have at least one negative element. The zero sum implies (together with the constraint that all elements are non-zero) that every tuple in either set has both positive and negative elements, thus removing what distinguished $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$.

The bonus question reintroduces the distinction, since now tuples in $\mathbf A$ are guaranteed to have a positive *first* element and tuples in $\mathbf B$ a negative *first* element, which isn't guaranteed by the sum condition, so now $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are again different – in fact now they are even disjoint (since no tuple has both a positive and a negative first element).

Answer (score 1):

The first question:

Suppose `(k,m,n,o)` is in **A**. `k` must be positive and the sum k+m+n+o must be zero, thus at least one of `m`, `n` and `o` must be negative. Without loss of generality, let's say that `m` is negative. Then the tuple `(m,k,n,o)` is in **B**, because `m` is negative and it is also equal to `(k,m,n,o)` because it contains the same elements. We could prove the reverse implication similarly.

The second question:

A is not equal to B. As a counterexample, take (1, (1,-1,-1)). This is in A, because 1+1+(-1)+(-1)=0, however, it is not in B because (1, (1,-1,-1)) gives (-1) + ( 1 + (-1) + (-1) ) = -1. Addition is commutative so regardless of the permutation of (1,-1,-1), we won't find an element of B that is equal to (1, (1,-1,-1)).

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here (or perhaps not, since the OP accepted this answer) -- for both sets, the sum is defined as the sum of the elements -- there's no prescription to invert the sign of the first element in forming the sum. The reason $(1,(1,-1,-1))$ isn't in $\mathbf B$ isn't that it would have a different sum there, but that it has a positive first element, whereas the first elements of elements of $\mathbf B$ are reuiqred to be negative.

Comment: Well, in the bonus question, the objects are of the form (k,(l,m,n)) for both sets. I understood this to mean that only the sum equations are different, not that the first element is different because in the original problem, B is defined as (-k,l,m,n). But I see how one can arrive at your interpretation.

Comment: Aha, I also see now how one can arrive at your interpretation :-) Perhaps the OP can enlighten us as to which interpretation was intended?

Comment: My bad. joriki is right here. The A set in the bonus question contains (k,(m,n,o)) and B set (-k,(m,n,o)) for $k \geq 1$ and $m,n,o$ non-zero. Will edit the question accordingly.