# Comparison of two collections of 4-tuples using combinatorics - more complicated version

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

My problem is to show that 2 collections of unordered 4-tuples - $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ - are the same.

I define a collection of objects as a set, in which multiple entries of the same object are allowed. Hence $A = <(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1)>$ would be a valid collection of 4-tuples. In order for collections $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ to be equal, they need to contain the same elements with the same multiplicities. For example $<a,a,b> = <a,b,a>$, but $<a,b> \neq <a,a,b>$.

My collections contain unordered 4-tuples $(k,m,n,o)$. Two unordered 4-tuples are equal iff they contain the same elements with the same multiplicities, regardless of ordering. For example, $(1,2,1,3) = (1,1,2,3)$, but $(1,2,1,3) \neq (1,2,2,3)$.

**Initial problem:**

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a collection of **all** unordered 4-tuples $(k,m,n,o)$ such that the following conditions hold. $k$ is an integer $k \geq 1$. $m,n,o$ are **non-zero** (positive or negative) integers. Most importantly, $k+m+n+o = 0$.

Let $\mathbf{B}$ be a collection of **all** unordered 4-tuples $(-k,m,n,o)$ such that the following conditions hold. $k$ is an integer $k \geq 1$. $m,n,o$ are **non-zero** (positive or negative) integers. $-k+m+n+o = 0$.

To clarify, the way those collections are constructed is as follows. First, let them be empty. Then, loop through all possible **ordered** combinations $k,m,n,o$. If such a combination satisfies the necessary conditions, add 1 instance of the 4-tuple in. Hence this process can result into identical 4-tuples being present more than once in the collection.

The goal is to show that $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$. As mentioned above, they need to contain the same elements with the same multiplicities.

**Remarks:**
I know they are not equal as I can find a counter-example. However, I wanted to pose this problem as an initial intro to my actual problem.

**My problem:**
Everything I have written above holds, except for the definition of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.

Now, I define $\mathbf{A}$ as a collection of all unordered 4-tuples $(k,m,n,o)$ such that $k$ is an integer $k \geq 1$, $m,n,o$ are **non-zero** (positive or negative) integers, and $k+m+n+o = 0$. However, the 4-tuple is inserted into the collection with multiplicity $k = |k|$ (i.e. $|k|$-times). For example, $\mathbf{A}$ might include $|a| \times (a,b,c,d)$ and $|b| \times (b,a,c,d)$, which are equal 4-tuples, but with different multiplicities. Those terms can be then grouped together for the purpose of comparing with $\mathbf{B}$.

The collection $\mathbf{B}$ is defined in the same way, except for tuples being $(-k,m,n,o)$ and the condition $-k+m+n+o=0$. The multiplicities of the terms are $|k| = -k$.

To clarify, let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be empty at first. Then I go through all possible $k,m,n,o$, and add $(k,m,n,o)$ and $(-k,m,n,o)$ respectively, and I'll do so $|k|$ times (multiplicities). I want to show that now, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ contain the same elements.

They are the same - I have written a program comparing the terms up to a certain limit on $k,m,n,o$. However, I would like to have a proof.

**Bonus:**
Let the multiplicity of a tuple $(k,m,n,o)$ be $|k|^N$ for integer N (including 0) (instead of $N=1$ considered previously). Show that **only** for $N=1$ $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$.

**Remark:**
I asked a seemingly similar, simpler question recently ( [Comparison of two sets of 4-tuples using combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352602/comparison-of-two-sets-of-4-tuples-using-combinatorics) ). I don't think I can apply its solution to this case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on [jachym's Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1355516/109292):

The construction of the set indeed causes each 4-tuple to be inserted into A **k**-times for each positive integer **k** in the tuple, and similarly for negative integers and B. Because of the k+m+n+o=0 condition, the sums of all positive integers and all negative integers must be the same.

For the bonus question, consider the tuple (1,1,1,-3).
For any **N**, the multiplicity in the collection **A** will be 3. However, the multiplicity in  **B** will vary. It's 1 for N=0, 3 for N=1, 9 for N=2 and so on. As N increases, the multiplicity will also increase.

Answer (score 1):

The 4-tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ has multiplicity in **A** equal to the sum of the positive integers in it. Its multiplicity in **B** is minus the sum of the negative integers. By the condition $a+b+c+d=0$ the multiplicities are the same and thus **A**=**B**.

For bonus question just use $(1,2,3,-4)$ as a counterexample.

Comment: In the bonus question, your example does not satisfy $a+b+c+d=0$, but I get your point. http://math.stackexchange.com/users/109292/petr-hude%C4%8Dek showed the same thing further down.